# Background Worker Initiate COM Component

Tags: c#, com, .net-4.0, backgroundworker

I am using a COM component which is absurdly slow (takes few minutes to give me requested data) so to keep the UI responsive, in my WPF application, I am thinking of using either Task or BackgroundWorker Classes to create a background thread, and disable all controls on UI to prevent any problems, as the component is not threadable.

The component is added to the project simply as a standard COM reference. The problem is that it simply doesn't work (including initialization using new) from any background thread. It works fine from the UI thread. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, rarely works.  There's different kinds of "simply doesn't work", you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: It's possible that the COM component is simply not meant to work, except on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to add `[STAThread]` attribute to `Main()`?

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
}
```

When the [STAThreadAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71tx0eb5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is applied, it changes the apartment state of the current thread to be single threaded.
Without getting into a huge discussion about COM and threading, this attribute ensures the communication mechanism between the current thread and other threads that may want to talk to it via COM.
This attribute is usually automatically applied to Main when you start a new UI project.

---

Or (as SLaks told me) you can try:

```
Thread t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
....

public void ThreadProc()
{
    // Thread function
}
```

You could also want to use

```
bool result = t.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

and check `result` value to be sure that your try was succesful

Comment: That's only for `Main()`.  You need to start a `new Thread` and call `SetApartmentState`

Comment: Thanks @SLaks: I edited my post to reflect your suggestion. Do you think it's better now? ;)

Comment: Adding it to `Main` will only affect the main thread.  (`Main()` probably already has it anyway)

Comment: @SLaks: yes, you're right (you're always right ;) ); anyway I'd like to leave that part... if OP wants to call COM object right from main thread. Do you think it's better if I delete my answer and you write yours? It will be better than mine ;)

Comment: Your answer is good enough; just clarify what `[STAThread]` does.

Comment: For simplicity I converted to use Tasks library this way. Thought of sharing this. (BTW it is the same concept of using STAThread attribute)
**
var sta = new System.Threading.Tasks.Schedulers.StaTaskScheduler(2);
Task task = new Task(InitializeDataSources,  TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
task.ContinueWith(TaskCompleted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
task.Start(sta);